# Prestashop - My class controller is not seen

Tags: php, module, controller, prestashop

I learn Prestashop and I try to make a module.

#### In my `/module2` I have:

-`module2.php` (the main file from `/module2`)
-`/views/templates/hook/module2.tpl` (has a link for `product.php` controller)
-`/controllers/front/product.php` (which is the controller)
-`/views/templates/front/product.tpl` (the view from `product.php` controller)

All is good in `module2.php` and `module2.tpl` appears. But when I press the link from  `module2.tpl` it sends me to the `product.php` controller which doesn't work well.

#### Error:

I used `@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to see the possible errors and an error occurred: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'module2productModuleFrontController' not found in /var/www/html/prestashop/classes/controller/Controller.php:142 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/prestashop/classes/Dispatcher.php(361): ControllerCore::getController('module2productM...') #1 /var/www/html/prestashop/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/prestashop/classes/controller/Controller.php on line 142`

`module2productModuleFrontController` is the name of class from my controller (`product.php`). 
The name format seems good because I know that I must use: 
 `name module`+`displayModuleFrontController` (module2 + productModuleFrontController).

I don't think I must look through `/classes` directory as Error says because I am not allowed to modify there.
I also *uninstalled* and *reinstalled* my `module2` from back-office but Error was still there.

### What do you think I should do?

Comment: Which version of Prestashop was this?

Comment: I actualy don't remember. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In your module `__construct` method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    /* your stuff */
    $this->controllers = array('product');
    /* your stuff */
}
```

Your class 'must' extend the `ModuleFrontController` class:

```
class module2ProductModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
}
```

PS: If you want to display errors, go in `config/defines.inc.php` and change the value of `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true`

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that. Please mark this answer as correct to help others ;)

Comment: I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Ok, under the down triangle at left of this answer, if you hover your mouse under that will appear a green check, click on it :)